# AWS MediaConvert - Add metadata to s3 output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert, aws-elemental

**Description:**

I would like to be able to add S3 Metadata to a MediaConvert Job Output but can't seem to find any settings that would allow me to do this. I am able to update the object metadata after the job has completed, but I need the Metadata to be available when the 's3:ObjectCreated:*' event occurs as I need that Metadata available in another Lambda function.

**Question:**

Is it possible to get MediaConvert to add metadata to an object in S3 when it completes a job?

Comment: No, it's not possible to let MediaConvert add custom metadata to the output S3 object.

Comment: Searching for a similar solution. Using MediaConvert to generate a preview video and images of frames. Also want some metadata like using ffprobe but looks like not provided by AWS.